# Basic Caching with ListView that is programmatically created (Listview + DataPager)

Tags: asp.net, listview, caching

Right now everytime the user uses the datapager the entire datasource is refilled and that takes time..

So is there a quick and easy why to use caching ? (I never used it) ... Or should I just store the eniter thing in a Session object and somehow detect if the intial data load has been made ?

```
 PersonBusiness pb = new PersonBusiness(new PersonRepository());

    if (personFilter == null)
    {
        listPerson = pb.GetAllPersons(strServer, strAppPath);
    }
 lvPersons.DataSource = listPerson;
    lvPersons.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

THis was alot easier than I thought it woudl be.. All I need was a few lines and listview and paging works.. one exxception is when a new filter is set you need to remove the cache

```
    if (Cache.Get("Members") != null)
    {
        listPerson = (List<Person>)Cache.Get("Members");
    }
    else
    {
        if (personFilter == null)
        {
            listPerson = pb.GetAllPersons(strServer, strAppPath);
            Cache.Insert("Members", listPerson, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), TimeSpan.Zero);
        }
        else
        {
            listPerson = pb.GetSomePersons(strServer, strAppPath, personFilter.FirstName, personFilter.LastName, personFilter.State, personFilter.Company, personFilter.Committees, personFilter.IndType, personFilter.MemberType);
            Cache.Insert("Members", listPerson, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), TimeSpan.Zero);
        }
    }
```